# Cannot control instances with factory method pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

One of the benefits of a factory is that it doesn't necessarily have to return a new object. It can instead return objects from an object pool.

This is great, but in order for the factory to create an object when it needs to, those object classes need public constructors. Therefore somebody could theoretically go straight to the class and ask for a new instance and the factory would have no idea. The object that was created outside the factory would not be added to the object pool.

Is there any way to stop objects from being created outside the factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can make your instance classes private nested classes of the factory.

Comment: If you are talking about a small amount of code/classes it's fine, imo. If not, I would go for a package-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a compelling reason for preventing objects' being instantiated other than in the factory? This kind of control usually isn't productive. Keep in mind you can never totally prevent that due to reflection. You just make it more annoying. If it's question of coding style, performance, or something like that in your project, you're better off using a static analysis tool like [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/), or [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to watch for object instantiations in the wrong place.

Comment: Something in my code needs to be aware of all instances created at all times.

Comment: If that's really the case, wouldn't you be better off making it an inherent part of the design of the object, rather than trying to force it to be true externally?

Comment: @GaryF Yes, I believe that would be the better solution. Unfortunately I have a bunch of these classes and I would have to repeat code in each of them because I can't find a way to make the code inheritable.

Comment: Exactly what @GaryF said. This is what constructors are for, and it's (almost) impossible to create objects in Java without calling the constructor. Otherwise, I stick by my answer: use static analysis to ensure that code complies with expectations.

Comment: You could also look at AspectJ for adding behavior to classes.

Comment: @RyanStewart It would be very easy with a simple `getInstance` factory method in the class itself. But all of my classes need the same `getInstance` static method and static methods cannot be inherited in Java.

Comment: Constructors, on the other hand, *can* be enforced and reused in inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: @RyanStewart Constructors require a new instance be returned. I don't necessarily want a new instance every time.

Comment: You said you need to "be aware of all instances". Add code to the constructor (manually or via AspectJ) to make this so, knowing that in Java, we mostly create objects using a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should make you clases private to its package

Comment: This works for someone working outside the package. However, someone working in the package would have to be aware that you should only create instances through the factory.

Comment: then you shoul follow @nerdytenor answer

Comment: If someone who reasonably has package doesn't know that they should use the factory, you've got a bigger communication problem. They'd be able to get round pretty much anything you do. Sometimes the solution isn't in the code.

Comment: @John: Put a comment in the documentation of this constructor. Maybe even a `@Deprecated` annotation, so the other user gets a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

They *could* have protected constructors, rather than public ones.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to control access to a constructor to various degrees:

1. Give the class a package scoped (default) constructor and have the factory exist in the same factory: If you do this, only classes in the same package can access that constructor. This should be good enough.
2. Make your classes private inner classes of the factory: Doing this ensure that only the factory can make use of them.
3. Don't do anything in code, but write some good documentation about why you think clients should use the factory: Sometimes it's okay to let people potentially shoot themselves in the foot, if they think they've got a good reason to do so outside what you imagine they might do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually recommend the following, and I would probably never do it myself.

Having said that, one thing you can do is have all the objects check if they're being constructed by the factory, and, if not, throw a suitable exception.

To do this, in the constructors of the objects just call `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`, then 'unwind' the stack until you get at the frame right after (before) the constructor. Now you can examine the caller and throw an exception if it's not the `Factory`.

This technique *can* prevent new object instances from being instantiated even via reflection.

Now obviously there's overhead in examining and unwinding the stack trace, and if the factory can't intern/cache previously constructed objects (i.e. it has to return a new instance every time) and you're calling it enough times all that can get costly.

Hence, the usual caveats of "just because it can be done, doesn't mean you should do it" apply. Then again, if you *really* have to do it, then it's good to know at least one way how.